# Chained dropdown list in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I want to create multiple drop down list in codeigniter, in my case when the user selects center the next list should provide the co-ordinater options of that center. Is it possible to provide loading the options from the database.

**view**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-lg-2">Select Center<span class="text-danger">*</span> </label>
    <div class="col-lg-9">
        <select name="center" class="form-control required">
            <option value="">Choose an option</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-lg-2">Co-ordinator<span class="text-danger">*</span> </label>
    <div class="col-lg-9">
        <select name="co-ordinator" class="form-control required">
            <option value="">Choose an option</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

**controller**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class House extends CI_Controller 
{

    public function __construct()
    { 
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->model('admin/Hose_model');
        $this->load->library('session');
    }

    public function index()
    {   
        $dis['res']=$this->Hose_model->display()->result_array();
        $this->load->view('admin/house',$dis);
    }
    public function add()
    {            
         $data['center']=$this->input->post('center');
         $data['co-ordinator']=$this->input->post('co-ordinator');
         $this->Hose_model->db_insert($data);
         redirect("admin/house");
         $this->load->view('admin/newhouse');               
    }  
}
```

**model**

```
public function db_insert($data)
{
    $query=$this->db->insert('hose_db',$data);
    return $query;
}
```

Comment: format the code at lest please ...

Comment: How this will Insert?? which function will trigger?? and how it get trigger ?? **No idea at all**

Comment: i want to select center and  co-ordinator option from database.

Comment: have to use ajax for that

Comment: yes @ Pathik Vejani

Comment: anybody, pls give me the answer.

Comment: call the ajax on onchange of select center and get the co-ordinator list from database  from that ajax call and bind it on co-ordinator select box